# Does ClusterIP service distributes requests between replica pods?

Tags: kubernetes

Do you guys know if a `ClusterIP` service distributes the workload between the target deployment replicas?

I have 5 replicas of a backend with a ClusterIP service selecting them. I also have another 5 replicas of nginx pod pointing to the this back end deployment. But when I run a heavy request the back end stops responding other requests until it finishes the heavy one.

## Update

Here is my configuration:

> Note: I've replaced some info that are related to the company.

### Content provider deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  frontend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  python-gunicorn
        image:  <my-user>/webapp:1.1.2
        command: ["/env/bin/gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "main:app", "--chdir", "/deploy/app", "--error-logfile", "/var/log/gunicorn/error.log", "--timeout", "7200"]
        resources:
          requests:
            # memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "0.25"
          limits:
            # memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "0.4"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: 8000
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1200
      imagePullSecrets:
        # NOTE: the secret has to be created at the same namespace level on which this deployment was created
        - name: dockerhub
```

### Content provider service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: webapp
    tier: frontend
spec:
  # type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: webapp
    tier: frontend
```

### Nginx deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          secretName: nginxsecret
      - name: configmap-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginxconfigmap
      containers:
      - name: nginxhttps
        image: ymqytw/nginxhttps:1.5
        command: ["/home/auto-reload-nginx.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /index.html
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1200
        resources:
          requests:
            # memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "0.1"
          limits:
            # memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "0.25"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
          name: secret-volume
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: configmap-volume
```

### Nginx service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxsvc
  labels:
    app: nginxsvc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

### Nginx config file:

```
server {
    server_name     local.mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://local.mydomain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        keepalive_timeout    70;
        server_name www.local.mydomain.com local.mydomain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_connect_timeout       7200;
            proxy_send_timeout          7200;
            proxy_read_timeout          7200;
            send_timeout                7200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ClusterIP service distributes the workload

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, service type `ClusterIP` uses `kube-proxy`'s `iptables` rules to distribute the requests roughly evenly in a `round robin` manner.

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace) says:

> By default, the choice of backend is round robin.

Although, the `round robin` distribution of requests may be affected by things like:

1. Busy backends
2. Sticky Sessions
3. Connection-based (if a backend pod has established a TCP session or a secure tunnel with the user hitting the `ClusterIP` multiple times)
4. Custom host-level / node-level `iptables` rules outside kubernetes

Comment: Do you know if the round robin algorithm for the request level? Or is it for the connection level? One request is answered by a single pod or multiple ones?

Comment: @Mauricio Upvote my answer and accept it if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks! https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace says _"Any `connections` to this “proxy port” will be proxied to one of the Service’s backend Pods"_. If the request is _not_ connection-based (UDP), the round robin distribution happens at the request-level. I have seen both in my testing.

Answer (score 4):

ClusterIP is implemented by `kube-proxy` by means of probability matching on iptables NAT rules, so yes, it is distributing requests more or less evenly among the pods backing given service.

Depending on your backend, this still may result in less then ideal situation where a portion of your requests is blocked on one of the backends as it awaits a heavy request to finish processing.

Also, keep in mind that this is done on connection level, so if you've established a connection and then run multiple requests via the same TCP connection, it will not jump between backends.

Comment: So, why my requests are not being answered while a pod is processing a heavy one?

Comment: well, for starters, the bottleneck can be in a different place, ie. db table lock. Need to know more about what you deploy to give any more hints.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: The nginx should be proxying to the cluster dns name of the python service, rather than localhost.

Comment: highly recommend reading this basically if you have Cluster-IP Service --> 4 pods it's not uncommon for 100% of 10k requests to go to the same backend pod vs evenly distributed! https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_clusterip

Comment: @neokyle I don't see where you draw this conclusion from. My experience is the opposite, ClusterIP services balance the traffic pretty well. Obviously this is L3 distribution, hence if the tcp connection stays open and is reused you will not switch backend pods. UDP aside, what is distributed is TCP connections, not HTTP requests, so yes, you can end up hammering one pod, but only if you do it via the same connection.

Comment: @Radek'Goblin'Pieczonka yeah I left details out of my short msg that are covered in the link. Basically, a lot of protocols like gRPC, HTTP2, Rest APIs and a few others tend to aggressively reuse connections by default. (so the 10k I mentioned is edge case vs generic, but ironically it's not a rare edge case if that makes sense.) Aggressive connection reuse is what can lead to the behavior I mentioned. (Also I learned that is one of the advantages of service mesh / one of the things they refer to when they say advanced load balancing, by preventing some of that aggressive connection reuse.)