# Pod load distribution in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, scalability, kubernetes-pod

I have a service in Kubernetes that receives Http requests to create users,

Only with 1 pod, it correctly reaches 100 requests per minute, after this, it has latencies, the point is that if you hold 100 requests with 1 pod, should you keep 500 requests per minute with 5 pods?

Because even with 10 pods, when exceeding 100 orders per minute, dont correctly distributed the load and appears latency in the services.

The default load configuration I understand is round robin, the problem is that I see that the ram increases only in one of the pods and does not distribute the load correctly.

This is my service yaml deploy and my HPA yaml.

Deploy Yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: create-user-service
  labels:
    app: create-user-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: create-user-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: create-user-service
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: key
          secret:
            secretName: my-secret-key
      containers:
        ### [LISTPARTY CONTAINER]
        - name: create-user-service
          image: docker/user-create/create-user-service:0.0.1
          volumeMounts:
            - name: key
              mountPath: /var/secrets/key
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "8080"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "2.5"
              memory: 6Gi
            requests:
              cpu: "1.5"
              memory: 5Gi
          livenessProbe:    ## is healthy
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthcheck/livenessprobe
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: create-user-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: create-user-service
  type: NodePort
```

HPA Yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: create-user-service
spec:
  maxReplicas: 10
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: create-user-service
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 75
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageUtilization: 75
  - external:
      metricName: serviceruntime.googleapis.com|api|request_count
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.type: api
          resource.labels.service: create-user-service.endpoints.user-create.cloud.goog
      targetAverageValue: "3"
    type: External
```

What may be happend?.

Thank you all.

Comment: The default load distribution is definitely not Round Robin. Kube Proxy does a random selection over the IP table it maintains. The load averages over time, but it certainly will not be exact at all times.  Please look at [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736107/default-load-balancing-in-kubernetes [link] for discussion on this same subject.